# Why does pre-compiling pyc files not give the expected results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyc

I have a situation which I really can't explain: I run a Python script on a system with read-only file system with pre-generated `.pyc` files for all Python-modules and I run it again after remounting the file system writeable. After the second run the script is being executed much faster.

That did not surprise me much yet - maybe the pre-generated `.pyc`-files had not been generated correctly in the first place. On the second run they would be re-generated and be written (located in the `__pycache__` folders) and re-used on the third run.

**note:** 
The script I'm experimenting with does nothing more than to import some native Python modules (`sys`, `os`, `argparse`, etc.) - there is no other performance relevant code. So the only performance relevant difference between each run is the precompiled byte code (as what I can think of).
There are no other relevant processes running on the machine.

**The strange thing is**: the content of **all** `__pycache__` folders does not change **at all**. I've copied the whole `/usr/lib/python3.5` folder and the folder containing my script *before* and *after* the remounting and there is **not a bit of difference**.

Where does Python store the information needed to run faster? Why don't the `.pyc` files (or their time stamp!) change?

**In detail**:

I'm currently trying to pre-compile Python-scripts before deploying them onto an embedded target with RO-filesystem and the results are not as expected (cannot observe any difference on timing).

Here is what I'm doing to observe the unwanted behavior:

- log onto target (rootfs mounted RO)
- run script: `time myscript.py`, runs for **5.7sec**
- run script: `time myscript.py`, runs for **5.7sec**
- ... (can be repeated, result is always the same)
- `scp` content of `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages` and folder containing `myscript.py` to a folder called `before`
- **update**: capturing all permission and time stamps of all `.pyc` files
- remount RW: `mount -o remount,rw /`
- run script: `time myscript.py`, runs for slightly more than **5.7sec**
- run script: `time myscript.py`, runs for **1.79sec**
- run script: `time myscript.py`, runs for **1.79sec**
- ... (can be repeated, result is always the same)
- `scp` content of `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages` and folder containing `myscript.py` to a folder called `after`
- **update**: again capturing all permission and time stamps of all `.pyc` files
- compare folders which I suspected to now contain modified `.pyc`-files:

  `diff -r before after`

  no differences
- **update**: comparing all time stamps and permissions captured before - no difference

I've also tried to manually modify one of the copied `.pyc` files in order to check whether `diff` really compares binary files but that works as expected.

After a reboot the system also behaves as expected when the cache files have been written (script runs fast).

For those who don't believe me:

```
root@machine:/data# cat myscript.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import argparse
import logging
import signal
import sys, os, shutil

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('hello')

root@machine:/data# time ./myscript.py 
hello
real    0m5.756s, user  0m4.326s, sys   0m0.773s

root@machine:/data# time ./myscript.py 
hello
real    0m5.740s, user  0m4.289s, sys   0m0.797s

root@machine:/data# mount -o remount,rw /

root@machine:/data# time ./myscript.py 
hello
real    0m6.005s, user  0m4.374s, sys   0m0.845s

root@machine:/data# time ./myscript.py 
hello
real    0m1.789s, user  0m1.283s, sys   0m0.288s

root@machine:/data# time ./myscript.py 
hello
real    0m1.787s, user  0m1.287s, sys   0m0.284s
```

(I've shortened some of the output but the numbers are correct)

(very strange) **Update:**

To track the time stamps of all `.pyc` files I've run the following command *before* and *after* re-running `myscript.py`:

```
find /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ -name *.pyc -exec stat -t {} \; > file-details-before/after
```

The result is: `file-details-before` and `file-details-after` are **absolutely identical**! Content looks like this (identical in both cases):

```
...
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_psosx.cpython-35.pyc 10676 24 81a4 0 0 e 2221 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555909 1499781288 4096
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_psbsd.cpython-35.pyc 12047 24 81a4 0 0 e 2223 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555909 1499781288 4096
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_compat.cpython-35.pyc 8393 24 81a4 0 0 e 2222 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555910 1499781288 4096
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_psmswindows.cpython-35.pyc 14488 32 81a4 0 0 e 2227 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555910 1499781288 4096
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_pslinux.cpython-35.pyc 28030 56 81a4 0 0 e 2224 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555909 1499781288 4096
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-35.pyc 37069 80 81a4 0 0 e 2220 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555910 1499781288 4096
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_psposix.cpython-35.pyc 3069 8 81a4 0 0 e 2219 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555909 1499781288 4096
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/error.cpython-35.pyc 2557 8 81a4 0 0 e 2226 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555910 1499781288 4096
/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psutil/__pycache__/_common.cpython-35.pyc 6188 16 81a4 0 0 e 2225 1 0 0 1499781288 1499555909 1499781288 4096
...
```

The number of `.pyc` files, their permissions and timestamps are equal i.e. `diff file-details-before file-details-after` shows no difference.

**Profiling:**

Before re-running with writeable filesystem:

```
time python3 -m cProfile -s cumtime ./myscript.py
hello
         11530 function calls (11346 primitive calls) in 2.423 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     19/1    0.020    0.001    2.423    2.423 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.001    0.001    2.423    2.423 myscript.py:4(<module>)
     21/4    0.004    0.000    2.422    0.605 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:966(_find_and_load)
     21/4    0.002    0.000    2.418    0.605 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:939(_find_and_load_unlocked)
     21/4    0.008    0.000    2.369    0.592 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:659(_load_unlocked)
     16/4    0.003    0.000    2.353    0.588 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:656(exec_module)
     42/8    0.010    0.000    2.319    0.290 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:214(_call_with_frames_removed)
       16    0.009    0.001    1.815    0.113 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:726(get_code)
       16    0.001    0.000    1.700    0.106 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:718(source_to_code)
       16    1.689    0.106    1.689    0.106 {built-in method builtins.compile}
        1    0.003    0.003    0.687    0.687 __init__.py:24(<module>)
...
real    0m7.611s, user  0m5.861s, sys   0m0.877s
```

and after:

```
time python3 -m cProfile -s cumtime ./myscript.py
hello
         11050 function calls (10878 primitive calls) in 0.730 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     19/1    0.024    0.001    0.730    0.730 {built-in method builtins.exec}
        1    0.001    0.001    0.730    0.730 myscript.py:4(<module>)
     21/4    0.005    0.000    0.729    0.182 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:966(_find_and_load)
     21/4    0.002    0.000    0.725    0.181 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:939(_find_and_load_unlocked)
     21/4    0.005    0.000    0.684    0.171 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:659(_load_unlocked)
     16/4    0.004    0.000    0.677    0.169 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:656(exec_module)
     26/4    0.001    0.000    0.638    0.160 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:214(_call_with_frames_removed)
        1    0.003    0.003    0.313    0.313 __init__.py:24(<module>)
        1    0.002    0.002    0.203    0.203 shutil.py:5(<module>)
       21    0.007    0.000    0.201    0.010 <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:879(_find_spec)
       19    0.001    0.000    0.187    0.010 <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:1130(find_spec)
...
real    0m3.102s, user  0m2.196s, sys   0m0.448s
```

Comment: There are too many variables here for anyone to give you a meaningful answer.  You need to profile it and see for yourself.  Use the `cProfile` module (included with Python) to run the code in both fast and slow case, and view the results using [`snakeviz`](https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz).

Comment: I've added some information regarding your comment. The script only imports modules on a machine doing nothing else - and it behaves as expected: running slow, before the `.pyc` files can be written, and much faster afterwards. The strange thing is only I can't find differences in any of the `.pyc` files..

Comment: It could be the mode of the .pyc files are relevant too, not just the bits - e.g., the modification times.  You said your script does nothing but imports native python modules, but I don't believe this - it can not take 5.6 seconds to import os, sys, argparse.

Comment: I'ts python3.5 on a single core arm-cpu @800MHz - and there are some more modules ('etc')

Comment: I've updated the question with timings for a script with demonstration only purpose.

Comment: just using 'time' is not really very useful for us.  perhaps you could provide the cProfile results.

Comment: What will happen if you run `python -B myscript.py`? If `-B` is given, Python won’t try to write` .pyc ` files on the import of source modules.[ref](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-B)

Comment: @frans You said you mounted RO, but where do the `*.pyc` files come from then? If the timestamp of a source file is more recent than the one of the corresponding byte code file then Python will recompile. So even if the source and the byte code file contain the same code Python recompiles in this case. For R/W mount the `.pyc` file is updated accordingly (the timestamp). So it could be that for the RO case Python is recompiling all the time because it can't update the timestamp of `*.pyc` files (which it does in case of R/W and so they can be reused).

Comment: The `.pyc` files are being generated by a Yocto (embedded Linux) before generating the UBIFS filesystem which gets flashed on the embedded target later. I think all major Linux distributions have to do this in some way (e.g. when packaging or installing modules) since the `site-packages` directory usually cant be written to by normal users.

Comment: @wim: I've added some `cProfile` output and compared the time stamps of all `.pyc` files (there is no difference at all!)

Comment: I might be missing something, but the numbers are actually make sense for me, every time you run your script on a writable system it has the speed advantage of the pycache, what's wrong with the numbers?

Comment: @Or Duan: The strange thing is that there seem to done **nothing** on the filesystem - no `.pyc` files get generated, modified or even touched - at least that's what I believe to observe

Comment: @yi xiao: running Python with `-B` shows the expected result: after remounting `/` RW the execution time does not change until I omit the `-B` flag.

Comment: Mostly this sounds like the compiled bytecode is stored elsewhere, or you're comparing the wrong things. A simple `strace` should show the difference between runs. [cache_from_source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.cache_from_source) might also be helpful. One detail of note is that the timestamp of your `.py` files must match that stored inside the `.pyc` files, so if an image is prepared it must preserve those timestamps; with things like FAT only storing even seconds, that can be a file system issue.

Comment: This is what I thought, too - I've just copied the whole file system using `rsync -a --exclude '/proc' ... remote-computer:/ rootfs` before and after the re-mount/re-run but there are no differences but some log files and the files I've generated since. The file system is UBIFS and as shown the file-stats don't change.

Comment: Have you run the strace? If it is a precompilation that affects later runs, it must be storing them using syscalls.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like both ubifs and Python normally use unix timestamps (second granularity). However, I'm not sure ubifs does so strictly; it uses struct timespec in cached structures and only seems to truncate in do_attr_changes.

Comment: Anyway - the stats are *identical* before and after the magic invisible caching..

Comment: You have repeated that, but the fact is the runs behave differently; one performs 16 compile calls the other does not. They do so for a reason, which will be visible (even if not obvious) in a syscall trace. You can also check e.g. `os.__file__` for which compiled file is in use.

Comment: Indeed, the profile shows the "slow" run is recompiling.  Python recognizes, somehow, the .pyc files were copied from another machine and refuses to use them.  The next steps are to execute with verbose flag (`python -v`) and look at the syscalls with `strace`.

Comment: @frans were you successful in resolving this issue? I see the same issue on a OE built ro rootfs using a device with eMMC...

Comment: 32bit not 64bit python right? You inconsistently mentioned copy & compare of `/usr/lib/python3.5` vs `/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages`. The packages imported (shutil...) are not below site-packages, why care about that dir? Did you also compare contents & mtime of all other `__pycache__` dirs' files, esp. `/usr/lib/python3.5/__pycache__`?